# I have two admob advertisement top and bottom in android

Tags: android

I have two advertisement on the same page but i want to create one advertisement.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context=".Search">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.ads.AdView 
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="MY - ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
       </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I added the advertisement this way but  i guess i have to add java code for this advertisement.However,if i add java code i have two advertisement top and bottom.
xml code provides bottom advertisement to show advertisement.xml code is enough to add advertisement ?

Java code is here :

```
RelativeLayout RelativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
AdView adView=new AdView(this,AdSize.SMART_BANNER,"MY - ID");
RelativeLayout1.addView(adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense. You want just one ad on your page? So why dont you remove all code / xml referring to the second one.

Comment: Because i did it firt time as i said  Is xml code  enough to add one ad on my page or  do i have to write code xml and java ? are they different way to add ad. ? firt way is writing xml code, second way is writing java code ?

Comment: So you want to know, if you need code and xml, or just xml to load an ad. But also say that the xml by itself works. Does that not answer your own question? I assume the `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` is making it work, and no code is required.

Comment: you said java code is not required ? the xml by itself works it is right but every tutorial which i read have java and xml code are required so I'm confused.That's all.

Comment: You can have your app banned if you show more than 1 ad on a page under policy. I had this happen and so stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you replied,

Yes, you only need one or the other.

**You do not need both**.

To explain the code below I have added comments:

```
//Obtains your main layout.
RelativeLayout RelativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
//Creates a new AdView
AdView adView=new AdView(this,AdSize.SMART_BANNER,"MY - ID");
//Adds this new adView, to your page
RelativeLayout1.addView(adView);
//Gets a new ad request
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
//Tells the new adView to show the ad.
adView.loadAd(request);
```

From this, we can see that it is creating a new `AdView`, adding it to the page, then loading an ad.

Where-as, using just the xml, an `Adview` already exists.. So there is no reason to create a new one. and having `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` in xml, loads the ad for you.

They are two ways, of achieving the same thing.

p.s. I prefer the xml way of doing it.

Comment: @user3139336 No worries :)